# How to keep session alive in WinRT WebView

Tags: javascript, windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, httpclient

I am using the following code share the cookie between **HttpClient and WebView** in WinRT

```
var pageUri = new Uri(TargetPage);

var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
var cookie = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie("key", pageUri.Host,    pageUri.LocalPath);
cookie.Value = "value";
filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(cookie, false);

  var request = new  Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, loginUri);
  webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request);
```

I am using this code to bypass **login request** in Web browser. But here the issue is after 5 minutes the cookie get **expires** and It again ask for credential for proceeding further. So my doubt is,

Is there any tweak available to make this browser **alive with the cookie / Session**. May be like injecting some Java Script code to browser or something similar to this.

I am currently sending **WebRequest** to authenticate again using **DispatureTimer** with interval of **5 minutes** and refreshes the cookie again and again. I don't feel it as a good workaround to this issue. Because it consumes un-wanted data and battery usage.

So anyone please help me to find a workaround to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing the right thing with the DispatchTimer.  I don't know why you feel that it's incorrect, especially since you're already kind of hacking the website by hosting it in a webview.